# TemplaVoila to Fluid & Gridelements converting

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid, extbase, templavoila

Have and issue converting a **TemplaVoila** based website,
I created the necessary gridelements and used templavoila flexforms for do ing that.
The issue I have is when I try to get the data of the flexforms

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<T3DataStructure>
    <meta type="array">
        <langDisable>1</langDisable>
    </meta>
    <ROOT type="array">
        <tx_templavoila type="array">
            <title>ROOT</title>
            <description>Select the HTML element on the page which you want to be the overall container element for the template.</description>
        </tx_templavoila>
        <type>array</type>
        <el type="array">
            <field_b53fc0 type="array">
                <type>array</type>
                <tx_templavoila type="array">
                    <title>Element hinzufügen</title>
                    <eType>input</eType>
                    <preview></preview>
                </tx_templavoila>
                <el type="array">
                    <field_78a762 type="array">
                        <type>array</type>
                        <tx_templavoila type="array">
                            <title>Element hinzufügen</title>
                            <eType>input</eType>
                            <TypoScript></TypoScript>
                            <proc type="array">
                                <int>0</int>
                                <HSC>0</HSC>
                                <stdWrap></stdWrap>
                            </proc>
                            <preview></preview>
                        </tx_templavoila>
                        <TCEforms type="array">
                            <label></label>
                            <config type="array">
                            </config>
                        </TCEforms>
                        <el type="array">
                            <field_7b6fd2 type="array">
                                <type>attr</type>
                                <tx_templavoila type="array">
                                    <title>Maske</title>
                                    <sample_data type="array">
                                        <numIndex index="0"></numIndex>
                                    </sample_data>
                                    <eType>image</eType>
                                    <TypoScript>10 = IMG_RESOURCE
10.stdWrap.wrap = background-image:url(|);
10.file.import = uploads/tx_templavoila/
10.file.import.current = 1
10.file.import.listNum = 0
</TypoScript>
                                    <proc type="array">
                                        <int>0</int>
                                        <HSC>0</HSC>
                                        <stdWrap></stdWrap>
                                    </proc>
                                    <preview></preview>
                                </tx_templavoila>
                                <TCEforms type="array">
                                    <label>Hintergrundbild</label>
                                    <config type="array">
                                        <type>group</type>
                                        <internal_type>file</internal_type>
                                        <allowed>gif,png,jpg,jpeg</allowed>
                                        <max_size>1000</max_size>
                                        <uploadfolder>uploads/tx_templavoila</uploadfolder>
                                        <show_thumbs>1</show_thumbs>
                                        <size>1</size>
                                        <maxitems>1</maxitems>
                                        <minitems>0</minitems>
                                    </config>
                                </TCEforms>
                            </field_7b6fd2>
                            <field_4f69c2 type="array">
                                <tx_templavoila type="array">
                                    <title>Produktbild</title>
                                    <sample_data type="array">
                                        <numIndex index="0"></numIndex>
                                    </sample_data>
                                    <eType>image</eType>
                                    <TypoScript>10 = IMAGE
10.file.import = uploads/tx_templavoila/
10.file.import.current = 1
10.file.import.listNum = 0</TypoScript>
                                    <preview></preview>
                                    <proc type="array">
                                        <int>0</int>
                                        <HSC>0</HSC>
                                        <stdWrap></stdWrap>
                                    </proc>
                                </tx_templavoila>
                                <TCEforms type="array">
                                    <label>Produktbild</label>
                                    <config type="array">
                                        <type>group</type>
                                        <internal_type>file</internal_type>
                                        <allowed>gif,png,jpg,jpeg</allowed>
                                        <max_size>1000</max_size>
                                        <uploadfolder>uploads/tx_templavoila</uploadfolder>
                                        <show_thumbs>1</show_thumbs>
                                        <size>1</size>
                                        <maxitems>1</maxitems>
                                        <minitems>0</minitems>
                                    </config>
                                </TCEforms>
                            </field_4f69c2>
                            <field_1a6a3a type="array">
                                <tx_templavoila type="array">
                                    <title>Headline</title>
                                    <sample_data type="array">
                                        <numIndex index="0"></numIndex>
                                    </sample_data>
                                    <eType>input</eType>
                                    <proc type="array">
                                        <HSC type="integer">1</HSC>
                                        <stdWrap></stdWrap>
                                    </proc>
                                    <preview></preview>
                                    <TypoScript type="NULL"></TypoScript>
                                </tx_templavoila>
                                <TCEforms type="array">
                                    <label>Headline</label>
                                    <config type="array">
                                        <type>input</type>
                                        <size>48</size>
                                        <eval>trim</eval>
                                    </config>
                                </TCEforms>
                            </field_1a6a3a>
                            <field_d696e9 type="array">
                                <tx_templavoila type="array">
                                    <title>Subline</title>
                                    <sample_data type="array">
                                        <numIndex index="0"></numIndex>
                                    </sample_data>
                                    <eType>input</eType>
                                    <proc type="array">
                                        <HSC type="integer">1</HSC>
                                        <stdWrap></stdWrap>
                                    </proc>
                                    <preview></preview>
                                    <TypoScript type="NULL"></TypoScript>
                                </tx_templavoila>
                                <TCEforms type="array">
                                    <label>Subline</label>
                                    <config type="array">
                                        <type>input</type>
                                        <size>48</size>
                                        <eval>trim</eval>
                                    </config>
                                </TCEforms>
                            </field_d696e9>
                            <field_055de1 type="array">
                                <tx_templavoila type="array">
                                    <title>Text</title>
                                    <sample_data type="array">
                                        <numIndex index="0"></numIndex>
                                    </sample_data>
                                    <eType>rte</eType>
                                    <TypoScript><![CDATA[
10 = TEXT
10.current = 1
10.parseFunc = < lib.parseFunc_RTE]]></TypoScript>
                                    <preview></preview>
                                </tx_templavoila>
                                <TCEforms type="array">
                                    <label>Text</label>
                                    <config type="array">
                                        <type>text</type>
                                        <cols>48</cols>
                                        <rows>5</rows>
                                        <softref>rtehtmlarea_images,typolink_tag,images,email[subst],url</softref>
                                    </config>
                                    <defaultExtras>richtext:rte_transform[flag=rte_enabled|mode=ts_css]</defaultExtras>
                                </TCEforms>
                            </field_055de1>
                            <field_373e2b type="array">
                                <tx_templavoila type="array">
                                    <title>Zum Produkt (Link)</title>
                                    <sample_data type="array">
                                        <numIndex index="0"></numIndex>
                                    </sample_data>
                                    <eType>link</eType>
                                    <TypoScript><![CDATA[10 = TEXT
10.field = field_0db16f
10.ifEmpty = {$SLIDER_INDEX_BTN_PROD}
10.innerWrap = <span>|</span>
10.typolink.parameter.current = 1
10.typolink.ATagParams = class="Button"
10.if.isTrue.field = field_373e2b
]]></TypoScript>
                                    <proc type="array">
                                        <int>0</int>
                                        <HSC>0</HSC>
                                        <stdWrap></stdWrap>
                                    </proc>
                                    <preview></preview>
                                    <TypoScript_constants type="array">
                                        <SLIDER_INDEX_BTN_PROD>{$_CONSTANTS.SLIDER_INDEX_BTN_PROD}</SLIDER_INDEX_BTN_PROD>
                                    </TypoScript_constants>
                                </tx_templavoila>
                                <TCEforms type="array">
                                    <label>Zum Produkt (Link)</label>
                                    <config type="array">
                                        <type>input</type>
                                        <size>15</size>
                                        <max>256</max>
                                        <checkbox></checkbox>
                                        <eval>trim</eval>
                                        <wizards type="array">
                                            <_PADDING type="integer">2</_PADDING>
                                            <link type="array">
                                                <type>popup</type>
                                                <title>Link</title>
                                                <icon>link_popup.gif</icon>
                                                <script>browse_links.php?mode=wizard</script>
                                                <JSopenParams>height=300,width=500,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=1</JSopenParams>
                                            </link>
                                        </wizards>
                                    </config>
                                </TCEforms>
                            </field_373e2b>
                            <field_3bf1df type="array">
                                <tx_templavoila type="array">
                                    <title>Zur Anwendung (Link)</title>
                                    <sample_data type="array">
                                        <numIndex index="0"></numIndex>
                                    </sample_data>
                                    <eType>link</eType>
                                    <TypoScript_constants type="array">
                                        <SLIDER_INDEX_BTN_ANW>{$_CONSTANTS.SLIDER_INDEX_BTN_ANW}</SLIDER_INDEX_BTN_ANW>
                                    </TypoScript_constants>
                                    <TypoScript><![CDATA[10 = TEXT
10.value = {$SLIDER_INDEX_BTN_ANW}
10.innerWrap = <span>|</span>
10.typolink.parameter.current = 1
10.typolink.ATagParams = class="Button Weiss"
10.if.isTrue.field = field_3bf1df]]></TypoScript>
                                    <proc type="array">
                                        <int>0</int>
                                        <HSC>0</HSC>
                                        <stdWrap></stdWrap>
                                    </proc>
                                    <preview></preview>
                                </tx_templavoila>
                                <TCEforms type="array">
                                    <label>Zur Anwendung (Link)</label>
                                    <config type="array">
                                        <type>input</type>
                                        <size>15</size>
                                        <max>256</max>
                                        <checkbox></checkbox>
                                        <eval>trim</eval>
                                        <wizards type="array">
                                            <_PADDING type="integer">2</_PADDING>
                                            <link type="array">
                                                <type>popup</type>
                                                <title>Link</title>
                                                <icon>link_popup.gif</icon>
                                                <script>browse_links.php?mode=wizard</script>
                                                <JSopenParams>height=300,width=500,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=1</JSopenParams>
                                            </link>
                                        </wizards>
                                    </config>
                                </TCEforms>
                            </field_3bf1df>
                            <field_a73d1b type="array">
                                <tx_templavoila type="array">
                                    <title>360° Teaser</title>
                                    <sample_data type="array">
                                        <numIndex index="0"></numIndex>
                                    </sample_data>
                                    <eType>check</eType>
                                    <TypoScript_constants type="array">
                                        <SLIDER_INDEX_PRODAN>{$_CONSTANTS.SLIDER_INDEX_PRODAN}</SLIDER_INDEX_PRODAN>
                                    </TypoScript_constants>
                                    <TypoScript><![CDATA[10 = COA
10 {
  10 = TEXT
  10.value = <h2>360

  20 = TEXT
  20.value = <span>&deg;</span></h2>

  30 = TEXT
  30.value = {$SLIDER_INDEX_PRODAN}
  30.wrap = <p>|</p>
}
10.if.isTrue.field = field_a73d1b

]]></TypoScript>
                                    <proc type="array">
                                        <int>0</int>
                                        <HSC>0</HSC>
                                        <stdWrap></stdWrap>
                                    </proc>
                                    <preview></preview>
                                </tx_templavoila>
                                <TCEforms type="array">
                                    <label>360° Teaser</label>
                                    <config type="array">
                                        <type>check</type>
                                        <default type="integer">0</default>
                                    </config>
                                </TCEforms>
                            </field_a73d1b>
                            <field_0db16f type="array">
                                <tx_templavoila type="array">
                                    <title>Zum Produkt (Titel)</title>
                                    <sample_data type="array">
                                        <numIndex index="0"></numIndex>
                                    </sample_data>
                                    <eType>input</eType>
                                    <proc type="array">
                                        <HSC type="integer">1</HSC>
                                        <stdWrap></stdWrap>
                                    </proc>
                                    <preview></preview>
                                    <TypoScript type="NULL"></TypoScript>
                                </tx_templavoila>
                                <TCEforms type="array">
                                    <label>Zum Produkt (Titel)</label>
                                    <config type="array">
                                        <type>input</type>
                                        <size>48</size>
                                        <eval>trim</eval>
                                    </config>
                                </TCEforms>
                            </field_0db16f>
                            <field_ad4f50 type="array">
                                <tx_templavoila type="array">
                                    <title>Video</title>
                                    <sample_data type="array">
                                        <numIndex index="0"></numIndex>
                                    </sample_data>
                                    <eType>check</eType>
                                    <TypoScript><![CDATA[10 = COA
10 {
 10 = TEXT
 10.field = field_0db16f
 10.wrap = <span>|</span>

 20 = TEXT
 20.field = field_1a6a3a
 20.wrap = <h4>|</h4>

 30 = TEXT
 30.field = field_055de1
 30.wrap = <h3>|</h3>

}
10.if.isTrue.field = field_ad4f50]]></TypoScript>
                                    <preview></preview>
                                    <proc type="array">
                                        <int>0</int>
                                        <HSC>0</HSC>
                                        <stdWrap></stdWrap>
                                    </proc>
                                </tx_templavoila>
                                <TCEforms type="array">
                                    <label>Video</label>
                                    <config type="array">
                                        <type>check</type>
                                        <default type="integer">0</default>
                                    </config>
                                </TCEforms>
                            </field_ad4f50>
                            <field_b2b651 type="array">
                                <type>attr</type>
                                <tx_templavoila type="array">
                                    <title>Youtube-Code</title>
                                    <sample_data type="array">
                                        <numIndex index="0"></numIndex>
                                    </sample_data>
                                    <eType>input</eType>
                                    <TypoScript type="NULL"></TypoScript>
                                    <proc type="array">
                                        <int>0</int>
                                        <HSC>1</HSC>
                                        <stdWrap></stdWrap>
                                    </proc>
                                    <preview></preview>
                                </tx_templavoila>
                                <TCEforms type="array">
                                    <label>Youtube-Code</label>
                                    <config type="array">
                                        <type>input</type>
                                        <size>48</size>
                                        <eval>trim</eval>
                                    </config>
                                </TCEforms>
                            </field_b2b651>
                        </el>
                    </field_78a762>
                </el>
                <section>1</section>
            </field_b53fc0>
        </el>
    </ROOT>
</T3DataStructure>
```

```html
tt_content.gridelements_pi1.20.10.setup {
     # ID of gridelement // eLearning 2 Spalter
     1 < temp.gridelements.defaultGridSetup
     1 {
          stdWrap.cObject = COA
          stdWrap.cObject {
               10 = TEXT
               10 {
                    data = field:flexform_field_4f69c2
                    wrap = <H1>|</H1>
               }

               20 = IMAGE
               20{
                    file{
                      import.data = field:flexform_field_7b6fd2
                      width = 256
                 }
               }

          }
          wrap = <li>|</li>
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Gridelements seems not supporting flexforms with sections in it what I did was using another extension to solve the work, called XPATH Content Object https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/cobj_xpath

```
10 = XPATH
10 {
 source.data = DB:tt_content:{field:uid}:pi_flexform 
 source.data.insertData = 1 

 return = string

 expression = //field[@index='field_7b6fd2']/value

 # configure the resultObj
 resultObj {

   cObjNum = 1
   1.current = 1
   1.wrap = <img src="uploads/tx_templavoila/|" />

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You use the wrong field for the header (header field should be field_1a6a3a). Also, you must set the path to the imported image as following

```
20 = IMAGE
20 {
    file {
        import = uploads/tx_templavoila/
        import.data = field:flexform_field_7b6fd2
        width = 256
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out but that seems not be the reason why that was happening.I mixed that in the example below but the problem seems to be because gridelements is not supporting flexforms with sections in it.
Btw I was ussing your extension to migrate Templavoila to Fluid/Gridelements. Nice tool!